# Can I extract API call graph from IDA Pro to xml file?

Tags: ida, idapython, idapro-sdk

I want to extract API call graph from IDA Pro to xml file for analysis. Can I extract API call graph from IDA Pro to xml file?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't extract an IDA graph to the xml file.

If you still want to use an external graph viewer, IDA supports two graph specification languages [Graph Description Language](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/GraphDescriptionLanguage) and the [D.O.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language))

Comment: The Graph Description Language seems to be quite readable and json-like though, so writing a parser for it to convert it to XML shouldn't take long.

Comment: I want to extract to xml because I want to analysis in data mining . The image can't use in data mining. May be I have to read data from IDA Pro. Can you suggest me how function call graph generate if not use the tool function call graph.

Comment: iirc the achicad package had a graphisoft gdl to xml convertor may be you could check if you can use that to convert the ida's gdl output to xml (lP_xml something.exe in archicad dev tools)